# Change true tone setting from the commandline

Tags: command-line, settings

Is it possible to change the true tone and "automatically adjust brightness" setting from the commandline?

Where does macOS saves preferences for such things?

I'd like to change the setting directly rather than an [applescript that launches setting and does this via the UI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378166/how-can-i-tell-if-true-tone-is-on-off-in-a-script)

Answer (score 1):

[Shifty](https://shifty.natethompson.io/en/) allows you to do this from the menu bar or by using keyboard shortcuts.

These settings are not stored on the file system anymore, they are most likely stored in the SMC. I don’t know of a command-line utility that can do this but it would be very possible to create one using Swift by taking inspiration from [Shifty’s source code](https://github.com/thompsonate/Shifty/blob/master/Shifty/CBTrueToneClient+Shifty.swift)

You would have to link to the following PrivateFrameworks to get access to the functions that can change the TrueTone and ambient light sensor state:

- CBTrueToneClient.framework
- CBAdaptationClient.framework